# Loading an image buried within several divs when the parent div is shown by a .show jQuery command

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script running on an ASP site that shows hidden DIVs when the id of a select form matches the div's ID:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name$="_77"]').change(function() {
        $(".select_77").hide();
        $(".select_77[id='" + this.value + "']").show();
    })
})
```

The form truncated to only one option for this example:

```
<select name="option____jdfhj387___77">
    <option value="1922">Raisins</option>
</select>
```

And this is one of the many divs that gets unhidden:

```
<div id="select_image">
    <div class="select_77" id="1922" style="display:none;">
        <div class="border">
            <div class="content">
                <img src="photos/option/1922.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The photos are medium sized, and it takes roughly 20-30 seconds for the page to load when I have 200+ of these images. Is there anyway to have the image load only when the parent div becomes visible, without having to manually put in every image url inside the script?

Comment: Didn't you just recently ask almost the exact same thing and then delete the question as people were trying to help you?

Comment: I deleted the question because I accidentally click "post question" when I didn't mean to, and hit stop in my browser without realizing the question was already posted.

Comment: It would have been better just to edit the question. There were some useful comments and answers posted on your previous question.  I was in the middle of suggesting putting the image src in a data- attribute when I got a big orange banner at the top of my browser saying the question was deleted.

Comment: I apologize, normally it says "You cannot delete this question because there are already responses" so I thought I was in the clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out after several hours of research.

I found and added code that renames an attribute of an img tag with a matching ID selected under the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name$="_77"]').change(function() {
        $(".select_77").hide();
        $(".select_77[id='" + this.value + "']").show();
        $("img.option[realsrc][id='" + this.value + "']").each(function() {
            var $t = $(this);
                $t
                .attr({
                    src : $t.attr('realsrc') /* Copies realsrc attribute and makes a src attribute*/
                })
                .removeAttr('realsrc'); /* Deletes the realsrc attribute */
    });
    })
})
```

Then I added class="option" and id="#" and renamed src= to realsrc=.

```
<img class="option" id="1922" realsrc="photos/option/1922.jpg">
```

Now when someone selects the option that matches the ID of the image, the image's realsrc will be renamed to src and it will download and appear!